# How to draw a zigzag line with UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, drawing

I have 2 known CGPoints and I want to make a jagged zigzag style line between the 2 points.  I know the distance between the points, and approximately how many lines to make, which is dynamically set based on the distance.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code sample in swift which I recently wrote to get this effect. This sample takes a view as input and applies the zig-zag effect to it. You can refer the code to create the effect for two points.

```
func applyZigZagEffect(givenView: UIView) {
    let width = givenView.frame.size.width
    let height = givenView.frame.size.height

    let givenFrame = givenView.frame
    let zigZagWidth = CGFloat(7)
    let zigZagHeight = CGFloat(5)
    let yInitial = height-zigZagHeight

    var zigZagPath = UIBezierPath()
    zigZagPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))
    zigZagPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, yInitial))

    var slope = -1
    var x = CGFloat(0)
    var i = 0
    while x < width {
        x = zigZagWidth * CGFloat(i)
        let p = zigZagHeight * CGFloat(slope)
        let y = yInitial + p
        let point = CGPointMake(x, y)
        zigZagPath.addLineToPoint(point)
        slope = slope*(-1)
        i++
    }
    zigZagPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(width, 0))

    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = zigZagPath.CGPath
    givenView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
}
```

You can tweak the zigZagWidth and zigZagHeight to get the effect of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

This will create zigzag line on top of side of view. You can pass number of edges you want in zigzag lines.

```
public extension UIBezierPath  {
func zigZagTop(_ rect: CGRect) -> UIBezierPath {
    let edges = 10
    let cornerWidth = rect.size.width / CGFloat(edges)
    let cornerHeight = cornerWidth/2
    for i in 0...edges {
        let newHeight = (i % 2) == 0 ? cornerHeight : 0
        if i == 0 {
            move(to: CGPoint(x:rect.size.width, y:newHeight))
        } else {
        addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width - cornerWidth * CGFloat(i) , y: newHeight))
        }
    }
    addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y:rect.size.height))
    addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y:rect.size.height))
    close()
    return self
}
}
```